# How to load environment variables in a config.ini file?

Tags: python, configuration, ini

I have a config.ini file which contains some properties but I want to read the environment variables inside the config file.

```
[section1]
 prop1:(from envrinment variable) or value1
```

Is this possible or do I have to write a method to take care of that?

Comment: @RoryDaulton - not a duplicate! That one read the values from `ini file` whereas I want to read the environment values in `ini file`. So that I can switch to default if env variables aren't available.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear to me as a Linux programmer. A Linux "environment variable" is a name-value binding provided by linux -- for example, the response to `printenv FOOBAR` from a command line. I think this question is "How do I use the value of a (Linux) system environment variable inside a a Python config file?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is late to the party, but someone might find this handy.
What you are asking after is **value interpolation** combined with **os.environ**.

### Pyramid?

The logic of doing so is unusual and generally this happens if one has a pyramid server, (which is read by a config file out of the box) while wanting to imitate a django one (which is always set up to read os.environ).
If you are using pyramid, then pyramid.paster.get_app has the argument options: if you pass os.environ as the dictionary you can use `%(variable)s` in the ini. Not that this is not specific to `pyramid.paster.get_app` as the next section shows (but my guess is `get_app` is the case).

app.py

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app
from waitress import serve
import os

app = get_app('production.ini', 'main', options=os.environ)
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, threads=50)
```

production.ini:

```
[app:main]
sqlalchemy.url = %(SQL_URL)s
...
```

### Configparse?

The above is using [configparser basic interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation).

Say I have a file called `config.ini` with the line

```
[System]
conda_location = %(CONDA_PYTHON_EXE)
```

The following will work...

```
import configparser, os
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config.ini')
print(cfg.get('System', 'conda_location', vars=os.environ))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Context

I had a similar issue while using `docker-compose` to start up an API, a PostgreSQL DB, and also run migrations with `alembic`.  Alembic reads the DB connection from the `alembic.ini` file which has:

`sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name`

In `docker-compose` I needed the `localhost` portion to reference the name of the `db` container instead: `postgresql://user:password@db:5432/db_name`

### What didn't work

I tried setting the `environment` in `docker-compose` and tried setting the value in the `.ini` file: `sqlalchemy.url = %(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@db:5432/db_name)`, but that didn't work.

### What did work

What finally **DID** end up working was updating `alembic`'s `env.py` file to read from the environment and overwrite the config value from the `.ini` file:

```py
from logging.config import fileConfig
from os import environ as env
from alembic import context
...
config = context.config
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
...
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = env.get(
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL", "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name"
)
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
```

This reads the value from the env, if present -- if not, it uses the default localhost value.  Later in the file, url is set based on the overridden env value: `url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")`

Answer (score -1):

I think :thinking_face, use .env and in config.py `from dotenv import load_dotenv()` and in next line `load_dotenv()` and it will load envs from .env file